# Sum records values ​from nested relations

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have 4 tables with accessories joined in kits:

```
Accessories
id  name         price
1   accessory1      43
2   accessory2      31
3   accessory3      13
4   accessory4       9

AccessoriesKit (table store relation between Accessories and KitMain)
id  id_accessories  id_accessories_kit_main
1                1                        1
2                2                        1
3                3                        2
4                4                        2

AccessoriesKitMain
id   name
1    kit1
2    kit2

AccessoriesKitMainRelatedToProduct (table store relation between Product with their all accessories kits)
id   id_accessories_kit_main   id_product
1                          1            2
2                          2            1
```

What is my problem - I get accessories kits related to product by ID of product and I need to SUM price of each accessory included to main kit and show it on view.

This is how I fetch accessories -

```
        $accessories = AccessoriesKitMainRelatedToProduct ::where('id_product', '=', $products[0]['id'])
        ->with('accessorieskitmain', 'accessorieskitmain.accessorieskit', 'accessorieskitmain.accessorieskit.accessories')->get()->toArray();
```

How can I sum prices and group it to related kit?

**EDIT**

I fetch array -  $accessories of accessories in my controller and pass it to my template where i loop it in foreach:

```
        @foreach($accessories as $accessory)
            @foreach($accessory['accessories_kit_main'] as $kitMain)
                <div class="accessory-title">
                    <h2>{{$kitMain['name']}}</h2>
                </div>
                @foreach($kitMain['accessories_kit'] as $kit)
                    @foreach($kit['accessories'] as $singleAccessories)
                        <div>
                            <h2> {{$singleAccessories['name']}}</h2>
                            <h2> {{$singleAccessories['price']}}</h2>
                        </div>    
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach

             !! AND HERE I NEED TO PUT SUMMED UP PRICES !!

             @endforeach
         @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$accessories = AccessoriesKitMainRelatedToProduct::where('id_product', '=', $products[0]['id'])
    ->with(['accessorieskitmain', 
            'accessorieskitmain.accessorieskit', 
            'accessorieskitmain.accessorieskit.accessories' => function($query){
                $query->sum('price');
    }])
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I have some question - array fetcheed by my way is exactly this same like yours, so how I should get gropued and summed up prices? ;D

Comment: EDIT. I mean on the view - I make foreach in template showing each value I need and how get this summed prices?

Comment: Can you please explain the case, the format of the data you want by the query?

Comment: you can use `groupBy('name')` after `$query->sum('price')`.

Comment: But then I get a error ''Call to a member function groupBy() on string" :((